# Submitting slurm array job with a limit above MaxArraySize?

Tags: bash, slurm

I need to submit a slurm array that will run the same script 18000 times (for independent genes), and I wanted to do this in a way that won't cause problems for my Uni's cluster.

Currently, the `MaxArraySize` set by the admins is `2048`. I was going to manually set my options like:

First array script:

```
#SBATCH --array=2-2000%300
```

N.B.: This should start at 2, because I want to skip the first line of the file that I am reading through using the array.

Next script:

```
#SBATCH --array=2001-4000%300
```

and so on...

But slurm does not like values above 2048 in the array.

Is there another way of doing this, which doesn't involve just a for loop submitting scripts for individual genes?

(All I can think are for loops, but then I lose the constraint option from slurm [`%300`], to avoid clogging the scheduler.)

Comment: is there any command to retrieve `MaxArraySize` in slurm? I can't get anything in `$ cat /etc/slurm/slurm.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit two jobs with

```
#SBATCH --array=1-2000%300
```

and, in the script, build the row index based on `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` rather than using it directly. In the first job:

```
ROWINDEX=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID+1))
```

In the second job:

```
ROWINDEX=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID+2001))
```

and so on.

Then you use ROWINDEX to select the line you want in your input file.