# Scheduling more jobs than MaxArraySize

Tags: slurm

Let's say I have 6233 simulations to run. The commands are generated and stored in a file, one in each line. I would like to use Slurm to schedule and run these commands. However, the MaxArraySize limit is 2000. So I can't use one job array to schedule all of them.

One solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908698/submitting-slurm-array-job-with-a-limit-above-maxarraysize), where we create four separate jobs and use arithmetic indexing into the file, with the last job having a smaller number of tasks to run (233).

1. Is it possible to do this using one sbatch script with one job ID?
2. I set ntasks=1 when using job arrays. Do larger ntasks help in such situations?

**Update**:
Following Damien's solution and examples given [here](https://doku.lrz.de/display/PUBLIC/FAQ%3A+Embarassingly+parallel+jobs+using+Python+and+R), I ended up with the following line in my bash script:

```sh
curID=$(( ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} * ${SLURM_NTASKS} + ${SLURM_PROCID} ))
```

The same can be done using Python (shown in the referenced page). The only difference is that the environment variables should be imported into the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this using one sbatch script with one job ID?

No. That solution will give you multiple job IDs

> I set ntasks=1 when using job arrays. Do larger ntasks help in such situations?

Yes, that is a factor that you can leverage.

Each job in the array can spawn multiple tasks (`--ntasks=...`). In that case, the line number in the command file must be computed from `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` and `$SLURM_PROCID`, and the program must be started with `srun`. Each task in a job member of the array will run in parallel. How large the job can be will depend on the MaxJobsize limit defined on the cluster/partition/qos you have access to.

Another option is to chain the tasks inside each job of the array, with a Bash loop (`for i in $seq(...) ; do ...; done`). In that case, the line number in the command file must be computed from `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` and `$i`. Each task in a job member of the array will run serially. How large the job can be will depend on the MaxWall limit defined on the cluster/partition/qos you have access to.

Comment: Aaah I see! Combining `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` and `$SLURM_PROCID` should give me the proper indexing. To followup, What would be the pros/cons of using a job array like this compared to, for example, a bash loop of size 6233 that calls an sbatch script with `ntasks==1`?

Comment: Better control of the jobs as a whole (cancel of the whole array, one email when everything is done, etc.) and, more importantly from the admin point of view, much much less burden on the Slurm controller